# SwipeRefreshLayout как остановить при помощи DataBinding

Tags: android, binding, android-data-binding, swiperefreshlayout

Никак не получается остановить **SwipeRefreshLayout**. Имеется фрагмент

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="vievModelList"
        type="ru.ch.ViewModelList" />

</data>
 <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        app:refreshing="@{vievModelList.flUpdate}">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItem"
            android:adapter="@{myAdapter}"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_doc_scan" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

В **ViewModelList** есть переменная

```
public MutableLiveData<Boolean> flUpdate = new MutableLiveData<>(false);
```

При свйпе по **swipeRefresh** запускается обновление с сервера, с крутящимся "колёсиком". После получения ответа от сервера переводим переменную **flUpdate** в **false**

```
flUpdate.postValue(false);
```

Но почему то "колёсико" не останавливается. Вот если повернуть экран то оно остановиться.
Если же в **ViewModel** вместо **LiveData** использовать **ObservableField**, то всё прекрасно работает.

```
public ObservableField<Boolean> flUpdate = new ObservableField<>(false);
```

В чем может быть проблема? Может я не тот параметр меняю у **swipeRefresh**?

Comment: Подскажите, что делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я, видимо, неправильно использовал **LiveData** переменную. После настройки **Геррера** и **Сеттера**, как показано ниже, всё заработало.

```
private MutableLiveData<Boolean> flUpdate = new MutableLiveData<>(false);

public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getFlUpdate() {
    return this.flUpdate;
}

public void setFlUpdate(Boolean status) {
    this.flUpdate.postValue(status);
}
```